# How can i pass object as parameter from a class to another class?

Tags: objective-c

i have three classes.. say one two three..
now i have an object of class one..
i want to pass that object from class two to class three as a parameter by calling a method which is in class three.

what all steps to be taken and kindly explain with examples ..

Comment: I’m not really sure what you are up to. Chances are that you would like to do something as asked in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4924350)?

Comment: Can I respectfully suggest that if you want to learn objective-c, you attempt to actually learn objective-c (plenty of books and internet sites to help you with that) instead of asking a question of the form "How do I do a very fundamental basic thing in language X". Then attempt to do something with your new-found knowledge, and ask questions if you run into difficulties with the basics.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you're after?

In your Class2 header declare a method that returns a Class1 pointer.

```
- (Class1*)objectOfClass1;
```

Implement Class2,

```
- (Class1*)objectOfClass1 {return [[Class1 alloc] autorelease];}
```

In your Class3 header declare a method that accepts an argument of pointer to Class1:

```
-(void) doSomething:(Class1 *)obj;
```

Class3 source, implement your logic:

```
-(void) doSomething:(Class1 *)obj {
    // Use your Class1 object here.
}
```

And you would call it on Class2 like this:

```
Class1 *obj1; //Object of class one
Class2 *obj2 = [[Class2 alloc] autorelease]; //object of class two
Class3 *obj3 = [[Class3 alloc] autorelease]; //object of class three

obj1 = [obj2 objectOfClass1]; //retrieve object of class one from object of class two 

[obj3 doSomething:obj1]; //pass object of class one into object of class three
```

Anyway, I recommend that you take a look at this simple tutorial: [Learning Objective-C: A Primer](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#referencelibrary/GettingStarted/Learning_Objective-C_A_Primer/)